# Единственное и множественное число

Tags: общие-вопросы

Как правильно: кавалер ордена Славы II и III степени или степеней

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

> кавалер ордена Славы II и III степени
> или степеней

Лучше так: *кавалер ордена Славы двух степеней.*

Или так: *кавалер двух орденов Славы.*

Comment: Не награждают "двумя орденами Славы". Награждают "орденом Славы II степени".

Comment: Люди знающие -- так говорят. И понимают, что это = III степень + II степень... См. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85+%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85+%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%22&tbm=bks

Comment: Люди **знающие**, как минимум, знают статут Ордена Славы. http://www.testpilots.ru/ref/slavy.htm

Answer (score 2):

А вам не кажется, что в вашем примере меняется смысл. В примере же, который приводит автор, указываются вид степени.

Корректно: кавалер ордена Славы II и III степени . Ед. ч. обусловлена тем, что степень одна. Если, например, от каждой степени были бы несколько видов, то тогда - степеней. 
В единственном числе согласуется: 
если единственное и мн. число имеют разные значения: ***католическая и православная церковь;*** 
Подробнее здесь:[Памятка по синтаксису](http://www.gramma.ru/EXM/?id=4.3)

Comment: По-моему, Ваш вопрос был адресован мне. Отвечу так:
кавалер ордена Славы двух степеней = III степень + II степень.
Других вариантов быть не может!

Comment: Слава, исходя из вашего получается, что у Ордена 2 степени. Но степень одна. III и II не являются отдельными степенями - это разные категории у одной степени.

Comment: ??? Степеней три! Награждение производится в порядке возрастания старшинства от третьей степени к первой. См. здесь: http://ordenrf.ru/su/orden-slavy.php

Comment: У каждого ордена одна степень. Три степени - три ордена. Следовательно, ед.ч.Ср. Орден II степени и III степени. если, например, было указано число, было мн.ч. Ср.: Ему вручили два ордена Славы -  2-й и 1-й степеней.Два ордена - две степени. http:[Википдия](//www.quickiwiki.com/ru/%D1%EF%E8%F1%EE%EA_%EF%EE%EB%ED%FB%F5_%EA%E0%E2%E0%EB%E5%F0%EE%E2_%EE%F0%E4%E5%ED%E0_%D1%EB%E0%E2%FB).Орден Славы состоит из трёх степеней: I, II и III степени.

Comment: Орден - *один*. Степеней "посвящения" - три. Причём, младшая - третья.

"Кавалер Ордена Славы II степени" *автоматически* предполагает "кавалер Ордена Славы II и III степени".

Comment: отвечен 22 часа назад
Серж: "А вам не кажется, что в вашем примере меняется смысл." Потерян знак вопроса. Зато далее - куча знаков, и все не на месте: "В единственном числе согласуется: если единственное и мн. число имеют разные значения: католическая и православная церковь; Подробнее здесь:Памятка по синтаксису"

Comment: shampar,не надо искать ошибок там, где их нет. Не зная меня, вы, следовательно, не знаете, как я пишу! В моем тексте - всего лишь опечатки. P.S. Где же вы усмотрели кучу знаков, которые, к тому же, не на месте?

Answer (score 2):

Обе формы верны. Чаще употребляется ед. число, потому что это термин, так записано в документе об учреждении ордена: учредить орден Славы I, II и III степени - как единый знак отличия разной степени "старшинства".

Но в бытовом употреблении мы представляем 3 ордена - золотой 1 степени и два серебряных и часто говорим: получил первую степень или получил две степени. Говорим и "получаем в порядке старшинства степеней", "Награждение производится последовательно: сначала третьей, затем второй и, наконец, первой степенью". Значит, возможно сказать и " орден Славы  II и III  степеней".

Вот, например, в Справке:
Высший военный орден "Победа" и орден Славы I, II и III степеней.

http://ria.ru/spravka/20131108/975346123.html

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, ситуация аналогична: "двое мужчин большого и малого роста". Не станем же мы говорить "большого и малого ростов". У каждого один свой рост. Аналогично и у каждого ордена одна степень.

Answer (score 1):

Для человека знающего - достаточно: "кавалер Ордена Славы II степени".

Для остальных - "кавалер Ордена Славы II и III степени". Т.к. "степень" относится не к "ордену" (то, что обычно называют "орденом" - является "нагрудным знаком Ордена"), а к "кавалеру" ("степень" - это вроде "положения в Ордене").